# Fetching "cancelled" events through the Office 365 REST API

Tags: calendar, outlook, office365, exchangewebservices, outlook-restapi

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to fetch "cancelled" events on Office 365. It seems like a pretty basic thing to do, however none of my attempts at figuring out how to do so have worked.

Reading the Office 365 API documentation, I can see that [the `Event` resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#RESTAPIResourcesEvent) has an `IsCancelled` boolean attribute, which should show `true` if the event was cancelled/deleted.

I've tried [the numerous methods of getting events through the API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations#GetEvents) with no luck. It seems that once an event is cancelled, it simply is removed from the returned results.

I also see that I can use [OData query parameters to try and filter the results](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#UseODataqueryparametersFilterrequests) of the event fetching response, so I even tried setting a `$filter=IsCancelled eq true` query parameter on the request, but all I got back was a response with an empty data array. :/

Is there something obvious I'm missing? The documentation's pretty light here.

Comment: Are you looking to only get canceled events for single meetings, or for an occurrence in a meeting series?

Comment: Ideally I'd get the results inline with a "calendarview" request. So for single events and for exceptions in a recurring series too. I'll take what I can get, though. :P

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I posted an answer.  If you can provide more details on your scenario, I may be able to provide an alternate way to implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today, the calendar REST APIs match Outlook behavior. So https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Me/Events?$filter=isCancelled%20eq%20true only returns deleted events that appear on a user's Outlook as "Cancelled: " in the subject line.  Once a user removes a cancelled meeting from their calendar, it won't be returned.  For meeting series, we don't have a way to currently return only the instances that were deleted.

Returning deleted events (single meetings, series, and specific instances of a series) is on our roadmap, as multiple partners have requested it.  However, I don't have a timeline to share with you at the moment.

Comment: Woah, so there's no way to fetch deleted events from the API? What about through the more antiquated EWS SOAP API?

And so the `isCancelled` attribute is really just a subject line parsing boolean? Where is that in the documentation?

Comment: Welcome to Microsoft API's!  :)

Comment: @venkat 2 years later and it's still not part of the API :(

Comment: We are also in need of being able to distinguish cancelled events from non-cancelled, if someone from MS is listening.

Comment: This is still an issue in 2021. We use a delta token and deleted event occurrences are not returned as one would come to expect. Come on, Microsoft!